# How to align view in layout using linear layout in horizontal orientation in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Can anybody tell me how to align the view in layout using linear layout in the horizontal orientation in android?

I want to view an image view on the left side, text in the center, and image view on the right side.

I want a layout like this:

```
ImageView                            TextView                          ImageView
```

Comment: You should post your *.xml first

Comment: show your layout file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding [`Weight`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) attribute

Answer (score 4):

Here is your layout: `imageview`-`textview`-`imageview`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text view" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help to solve your problem...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:gravity="left|center_vertical">

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
       </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```